# How to create a hasOne association that joins on multiple foreign keys via an OR condition?

Tags: php, cakephp, join, foreign-keys, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to join a table (Connections) twice from another table (Ports).

The conditions are:

- One port can have one or no connection
- One connection has one from-port and one to-port

---

The structure is:

Table Ports:

- id
- number

Table Connections:

- id
- port_from_id
- port_to_id
- name

So now I want to join from Ports to Connections.

Cake always gives me this:

```
LEFT JOIN connections Connections ON Ports.id = (Connections.port_from_id)
```

But it has to be:

```
LEFT JOIN connections Connections ON Ports.id = (Connections.port_from_id) OR Ports.id = (Connections.port_to_id)
```

or something equivalent.

My Ports-Model actually looks like this:

```
$this->hasOne('Connections', [
            'foreignKey' => 'port_from_id',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT'
        ]);
```

**How can I get the OR-Condition in my join?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to disable the associations foreign key handling (IIRC this only works for `hasOne` associations using the `JOIN` strategy, it *might* work for `belongsTo` too), and supply the conditions on your own, as multiple foreign keys aren't supported (unlike composite foreign keys).

Something along the lines of:

```
use Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression;

// ...

$this->hasOne('Connections', [
    'foreignKey' => false,
    'conditions' => [
        'OR' => [
            'Connections.port_from_id' => new IdentifierExpression($this->aliasField('id')),
            'Connections.port_to_id' => new IdentifierExpression($this->aliasField('id')),
        ]
    ]
]);
```

That should create SQL similar to:

```sql
LEFT JOIN
    `connections` `Connections` ON (
        `Connections`.`port_from_id` = (`Ports`.`id`) OR
        `Connections`.`port_to_id` = (`Ports`.`id`)
    )
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations > HasOne Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasone-associations)**

Comment: This is 100% what I asked for. Thank you very much! So I tried to reconstruct your solution with the cakephp-documentation. But it's not explained imo. So I wouldn't have found the answer by myself :-/